# Why are visitors to my site following absolute links as if they're relative?

Tags: html, logging, hyperlink, server

Every page on my website has a navbar with some absolute links, to pages like `/archive` and `/atom.xml`. These are present on pages like `/post/post-title`.

In my access logs, I'm seeing heaps of requests for paths like `/post/post-title/archive` and `/post/post-title/atom.xml`.

Assuming that I haven't just stuffed up a link somewhere (i.e., missed a slash), is there something else I might be doing wrong that's causing some clients to follow absolute links as if they're relative? Or is it just weird bots being weird?

Answer (score 0):

Links that have the forward slash before it should load at any folder in your web project with the main domain name.

If you have like this:

```
domain.com/index.php
domain.com/archive/index.php
```

and both index.php files have the following:

```
<a href="/">home</a>
<a href="/archive">archive</a>
```

all the links in both files are absolute links like:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/">home</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/archive">archive</a>
```

Having relative links could be produced from two issues:

```
1- Having a ./ rather than / in your links. (And that is the best guess)
2- Bots understands links and love links with "/" not with "http://domain.com/"
but you might uploaded a file with a ./ link before
and bots got it and you have it recorded.
```

Moreover, relative links are processed inside the main folder which they are inside, for example:

Putting the following:

```
<a href="./another_directory">Other Page</a>
<a href="./archive">archive</a>
```

inside:

```
domain.com/archive/index.php
```

will leed to:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/another_directory">Other Page</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/archive/archive">archive</a>
```